# Where is NSTemproryDirectory present?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image-caching

I am doing image caching and I am saving the files to a temporary directory NSTemporaryDirectory. Its seen in log as /var/folders/.... .Where is this thing present. I am currently doing all this in the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following line to find out:

```
NSLog(NSTemporaryDirectory());
```

Gives me the path path like this: /var/folders/c9/c9ooh947H2WloiBIdpTdcU+++TI/-Tmp-/

You can browse there in terminal:

```
cd /var/folders/c9/c9ooh947H2WloiBIdpTdcU+++TI/-Tmp-/
```

/var folder is hidden on MacOS and is not shown in Finder by default. You can switch on showing hidden folders using this terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
```

After that it must become visible in Finder in root folder

Comment: Didnt had much knowledge about the mac. Thanks.